# Convert Code to C#

Tags: c#

I was looking into random number generators and found pseudo code for one:

```
function Noise1(integer x)
    x = (x<<13) ^ x;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    
end function
```

I would like to convert this into C# but I get all kinds of error like invalid expressions and ")" expected. This is what I have so far how can I convert it?

```
double Noise(int x) {
    x = (x<<13) ^ x;
    return ( 1.0 - ((x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you use the Random class that is part of the .Net Framework?

Comment: plus this doesn't seem very random.

Comment: @Daniel yep, this is a terrible implementation of a ”RNG”

Comment: "_but I get all kinds of error like invalid expressions and ")" expected_"  --> use visual studio and resharper ;)

Comment: This is a pseudo random algorithm for perlin noise. Nice up-votes on pointless comments though >_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what language you've started with, but in C# hex constants should look differently: change `7fffffff` to `0x7fffffff`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .Net Framework random object

```
Random rng = new Random();
return rng.Next(10)
```

But I strongly recommend you to read this article from Jon Skeet about random generators

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: tested and reported a non-null sequence

1. Convert your hexadecimal constants to use "0x" prefix
2. Convert int <-> double carefully
3. Split the expression to make it a little bit more readable

Here's the code and unit test (strange results though):

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static Int64 Noise(Int64 x) {
             Int64 y = (Int64) ( (x << 13) ^ x);

             Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());

             Int64 t = (y * (y * y * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589);

             Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());

             Int64 c = t < 0 ? -t : t; //( ((Int32)t) & 0x7fffffff);

             Console.WriteLine("c = " + c.ToString());

             double b = ((double)c) / 1073741824.0;

             Console.WriteLine("b = " + b.ToString());

             double t2 = ( 1.0 - b);
             return (Int64)t2;
        }

        static void Main()
        {

           Int64 Seed = 1234;

           for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
           {
               Seed = Noise(Seed);
               Console.WriteLine(Seed.ToString());
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +0. Unless you are 100% sure that in OP's source language `^` is Pow you translation is different

Comment: its output: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Comment: You're right, I've fixed it a little but still getting zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting (yet)  :))))